# How to infinite scroll last fragment from multiple fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, infinite-scroll

I have multiple fragment in one activity and want last fragment to infinite scroll, but addOnScrollListener not working when scrolling.

I have success to implement infinite scroll in activity and in a fragment. 
In this case I want to implement infinite scroll in activity with multiple child fragment and the only one can infinite scroll is last fragment. When i use addOnScrollListener on last fragment my code not working, I realize the one scrolling is my activity not my fragment that why addOnScrollListener i my fragment not work.

Im using this code for activity and fragment :

```
public void onScrolled(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "yeah", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            visibleItemCount = layoutManager.getChildCount();
            totalItemCount = layoutManager.getItemCount();
            pastVisibleItemCount = layoutManager.findLastVisibleItemPosition();
            if (dy > 0) {
                if (isLoading) {
                    if (totalItemCount > previousTotal) {
                        isLoading = false;
                        previousTotal = totalItemCount;
                    }
                }
                if (!isLoading && (totalItemCount - visibleItemCount) <= (pastVisibleItemCount - itemTreshold)) {
                    page++;
                    loadMore();
                    isLoading = true;
                }
            }
        }
```

How can I archive only the last fragment can infinite scroll from that case?